Jetpack Compose: Transparent "fade" gradient in BottomBar
I want to add faded bottombar background to my custom NavigationBar I made.
It is accepting Transparent color and solid color but if I want to place there verticalGradient, it returns only solid color. This behavior is not happening if I use it in any other component such as Box.
It might be bug with Scaffold component but I'm not sure.
What I want to achieve is basically that I have verticalScroll inside my content in Scaffold and if I scroll down and content is going behind buttomBar, it is clipped by its background which suppose to be transparent at the top and slowly fade to solid color (thats why I want to wrap it with Box with verticalGradient). If I set that Box to Transparent, it is transparent and its not clipping my content, but gradient is for some reason not supported. It transforms into solid color no matter what startY/endY I set there.
I'm using this technique with verticalGradient in Screen background components where bottom component has faded edge and its working without any issues. It's just if its used in Scaffold bottomBar it is ignored.
val backgroundColor = Brush.verticalGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            Color.Transparent,
            tabColors.backgroundBottom,
        ),
        startY = 0f,
        endY = 50f,
        tileMode = TileMode.Clamp,
    )

Scaffold (
        bottomBar = {
            if (isTabBarVisible) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(backgroundColor)
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    TabBar(
                        navController = navController,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.SplashData,
        ) {
            ... navigation to screens
        }
    }

Here is visual representation what I want to achieve.
White == Transparent
Scrollable Content == Content displayed by NavHost (Composable Screens with lifecycle)
"Fade" Background should be part of the TabBar because there is Content (screens) where Navigation bottom bar is hidden and I dont want to have fade there.

This is how it looks now if I pass there verticalGradient (it takes non-transparent color as solid one) which is causing clipping of scrollable content behind tab bar (bottom bar).


Could you add something visual of what you want?

Added to the post

That's not bug. Scaffold measures content after measuring bottomBar height. Then places content then BottomBar as Column does, bottomBar below content. You, however, expecting it to behave like a Box

You can add your BottomBar and NavHost in a Box inside content slot

Won't I lose navigationBarsPadding feature in case I show SnackBar then? Scaffold is offsetting that (same for Action Buttons if needed). Don't want to show Snackbar over NavigationBar content

Adjusting a new padding value from the inner padding of the Scaffold and setting the bottom to zero may be sufficient to solve the problem. This way, you won't have to worry about the Snackbar.
Scaffold(
    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
    bottomBar = {
       // ur bottom bar
    }
) { innerPadding ->

    val paddingValues = PaddingValues(
        start = innerPadding.calculateStartPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
        top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
        end = innerPadding.calculateEndPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
        bottom = 0.dp
    )

    NavHost(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues),
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.SplashData,
    ) {
        ... navigation to screens
    } 
}


This would also work because bottomPadding comes from BottomBarHeight. Setting it zero would let content to be occupy full height of Scaffold - topAppbar if available.

That's right. It preserves the existing Scaffold's inner padding. Also there is no need to make any adjustments to the Snackbar. If a bottom bar is already being drawn, the Snackbar will always appear on top of it.

That's not a bug. Scaffold first measures bottomBar slot contents then measures content slot with constraints.maxHeight- topAppbar height then passes BottomBarHeight as inner padding. So, using this Padding values you subtract bottomBarHeight as well.
   // Update the backing state for the content padding before subcomposing the body
    val insets = contentWindowInsets.asPaddingValues(this)
    contentPadding.paddingHolder =
        PaddingValues(
            top =
                if (topBarPlaceables.isEmpty()) {
                    insets.calculateTopPadding()
                } else {
                    0.dp
                },
            bottom =
                if (bottomBarPlaceables.isEmpty() || bottomBarHeight == null) {
                    insets.calculateBottomPadding()
                } else {
                    bottomBarHeight.toDp()
                },
            start = insets.calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection),
            end = insets.calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection)

Then each slot is placed closely to how Column works.
https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Scaffold.kt;drc=14315ef9dde9631c946b256f7fccdb8c34bc7f31;l=532
val bodyContentHeight = layoutHeight - topBarHeight

val bodyContentPlaceables =
    subcompose(ScaffoldLayoutContent.MainContent) { content(contentPadding) }
        .fastMap { it.measure(looseConstraints.copy(maxHeight = bodyContentHeight)) }

layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
    // Placing to control drawing order to match default elevation of each placeable

    bodyContentPlaceables.fastForEach { it.place(0, topBarHeight) }
    topBarPlaceables.fastForEach { it.place(0, 0) }
    snackbarPlaceables.fastForEach { it.place(0, layoutHeight - snackbarOffsetFromBottom) }
    // The bottom bar is always at the bottom of the layout
    bottomBarPlaceables.fastForEach { it.place(0, layoutHeight - (bottomBarHeight ?: 0)) }
    // Explicitly not using placeRelative here as `leftOffset` already accounts for RTL
    fabPlaceables.fastForEach {
        it.place(fabPlacement?.left ?: 0, layoutHeight - (fabOffsetFromBottom ?: 0))
    }
}

Then it places content then bottomBar below content like Column does.
If you wish content to cover place below bottomBar too. You can use Modifier.layout with content to increase its size by bottomBarHeight
@Preview
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding(),

        bottomBar = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.height(48.dp).fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text("Bottom Bar Mock")
            }
        }
    ) { paddingValues: PaddingValues ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .layout { measurable: Measurable, constraints: Constraints ->

                    val bottomBarHeight = 48.dp.roundToPx()
                    val looseConstraints =
                        constraints.copy(
                            minHeight = constraints.maxHeight + bottomBarHeight,
                            maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight + bottomBarHeight
                        )
                    val placeable = measurable.measure(looseConstraints)

                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.placeRelative(0, bottomBarHeight / 2)
                    }
                }

                .border(4.dp, Color.Blue),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Hello world")
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Show snackbar")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

or can add BottomBar as part of content slot. And for Snackbar, you can override SnackBarHost and add padding to bottom as big as bottomBar.
@Composable
fun Test() {

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding(),
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 48.dp),
                hostState = it
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues: PaddingValues ->

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Blue),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Hello world")
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Show snackbar")
                }
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.height(48.dp).fillMaxWidth().background(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green))
                )
            ) {
                Text("Bottom Bar Mock")
            }
        }
    }
}

